# When is the sum of two diverging sequences dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $u_n$ and $v_n$ be two sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$which tend to $+\infty$ such that $u_{n+1}-u_n$ tends to $0$.

Is it necessarily true that $\{u_n-v_m\ | (n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2\}$ is dense in  $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the set is always dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. Since $u_{n + 1} - u_n$ converges to zero, we may choose an $N > 0$ so that $|u_{n + 1} - u_n| < \varepsilon$ holds for all $n \ge N$.

Since $v_n$ diverges, we can fix an $m > 0$ with $u_N - x < v_m$.

Now let us consider the sequence $r_k = u_{N + k} - v_m$. Since this sequence diverges to infinity, there must be a smallest integer $k_0$ with $r_{k_0} > x$. Since $r_0 = u_N - v_m < x$, we know $k_0 > 0$. From our choice of $N$, we can conclude that
$$r_{k_0 - 1} = r_{k_0} - (u_{N + k_0} - u_{N + k_0 - 1}) > x - \varepsilon$$
holds.

By definition of $k_0$ we also have $r_{k_0 - 1} < x$. Combining both these inequalities we get $|r_{k_0 - 1} - x| < \varepsilon$, which proves the original claim.